# find and replace value in stored procedure [MSSQL]

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a temp table `#temp321` which contain like below info:

```
id|sourceFields|DestinationFields
---------------------------------
1 |c2          |c102
-------------------------
2 | c4         |c104
-----------------------
```

Also i have a where clause into a variable `@where_value` like:

```
c1='v11' and c2='v22' and c3='v33' and c4='v44'
```

Now i need  only the destinationfields info into the @where_value .

Expected result into @where_value is : `c102='v22' and c104='v44'`

how can i get it.please help.

Comment: Please post the stored procedure definition.

Comment: i am not sure, what type of definition you want.i have to do it into a stored procedure.that's it.

Comment: Your question title mentions a stored procedure...can we have the stored procedure code? Or the code you're using to select from the table?

Comment: the procedure i almost 154 lines.it's difficult to post.it's just a problem into a portion of the procedure.

Comment: OK, post the relevant portion or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the full code. It's difficult to help when we don't have complete information on the problem.

Comment: its posted into http://pastebin.com/SXWmH9hD.Please check the line number 111 "-- i need to fix the problem here"

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @Var=@Var + CAST(DestinationFields as Varchar(30))+'='+ dbo.F_GetValue4Key(@where_value,sourceFields) +' AND '
from #temp321

Select @Var= SubString(@var,1,LEN(@var)-4)
```

Assuming your Wherestring looks like:

```
Select @where_value ='c1=''v11'' and c2=''v22'' and c3=''v33'' and c4=''v44'''
```

using this function

```
Create Function F_GetValue4Key(@p varchar(2000),@k varchar(2000)) Returns Varchar(50) as
begin
  Declare @Result Varchar(50)
  Declare @pos int
  Declare @pos1 int
  Declare @pos2 int
  Select @pos=CHARINDEX( @k+'=',@p)
  Select @pos1=CHARINDEX( '''',@p,@pos)
  Select @pos2=CHARINDEX( '''',@p,@pos1+1)

  Select @Result=SUBSTRING(@p,@pos1,@pos2-@pos1+1)
  Return @Result
end
```

Comment: sorry. you may change your code. because it's result shows c2='c102' AND c4='c104'. but my expected result is: c102='v22' and c104='v44'

Comment: You have to help us help you. Getting an answer that isn't perfect is due to the quality and completeness (or lack thereof) of your provided information. Frankly, you've been given a huge boost by getting a bunch of working code, that just needs tweaks. So update your question with what we need to know to fix the given code.